# php optimizing code for foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm developing something like a simple and purpose-specific cms.

I'm using a db class that outputs an array as a result from the query, but this array varies in structure depending on the mysql_num_rows.

If there is only one result it outputs a simple array, otherwise it outputs a nested array.

So, I must check the structure of the array to decide whether to do a loop with foreach, or just print the results.

with simple mysql_fetch_assoc we can use while() and then there is no problem with the number of rows. but with an array we must check it.

Till now everything is OK.

The problem is that the code will be repeated for the two conditions. with a slight change in the array name.

The array name is $res, if one result it will be `$res['anything here']`, else, because we have to use `foreach($res as $row)`, the array will be `$row['anything here']`.

So the code looks ugly and very big. Please take a lool at it here: http://mohamedkadri.com/code.html and tell me how to make it simpler and smaller.

Comment: "I'm using a db class that outputs an array as a result from the query, but this array varies in structure depending on the mysql_num_rows." Sounds like a terrible idea. Change that behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simple:

Change your DB layer so you can force it to return a list of rows even if there's just a single row. That's the only proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a great approach. I'd suggest changing your DB class so you have a different method to call depending on whether the query will return one row or multiple. E.g. in the Zend Framework database classes there is `fetchRow` and `fetchAll`. This will make it much easier for you to deal with the data you get back.

Another option might be to just always return a nested array even if there was only one row. That way the code to process the data will always be the same.

Comment: A separate function to fetch only a single row or `null` if there are zero rows is usually a nice thing if you know you won't get more than one row ever (`WHERE id = ...`). However, a pseudo-smart function doing this or returning a list of rows is a horribel idea.

Comment: OK i have a new question that contains the main code that qenerates this array, please help me modify it to force it output a nested array. thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454420/force-nested-array