# force nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code which returns a simple array if one result is found and a nested array if more.

```
$query = @mysql_query( $q );
if ( $query ) {
    $this->num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $query );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $this->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $r = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
        $key = array_keys( $r );
        for ( $x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++ ) {
            // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
            if( !is_int( $key[$x] ) ) {
                if ( mysql_num_rows( $query ) > 1 ) {
                    $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                } else if ( mysql_num_rows( $query ) < 1 ) {
                    $this->result = null;
                } else {
                    $this->result[$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

How to force it to always return a nested array and not a simple one?

Comment: First things first: You have an `else if` statement without an `if.` Can you correct the code and repost when you don't have syntax errors?

Comment: maybe it's wrong but it's actually working like that and I don't know how :)

Comment: This is also bad syntax (unbalanced parens) - else if ( mysql_num_rows( $query ) result = null; are you sure it's working?

Comment: @medk: I found the problem. Your code was all there, but was improperly formatted for SO. This is now fixed.

Comment: why can't you just use `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: @George: I always accept the right answers, but there are some questions that have no answers maybe :)

Comment: @medk: There's a solution for that, too: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: your method doesn't even return the results? That is a strange class. Can you post it in full, I suspect there's much more wrong with it.

Comment: @phant0m: the full class is here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql/ but I made huge mods on it and it works just fine except that I want to always force a nested array as the result

Comment: @medk: Do not use this class, it's heavily flawed!

Comment: @George Cummins: He just accepted an answer I posted last year which had one of those comments. About time he did...

Comment: @BoltClock: Great news! Congratulations on getting the check. @medk: Your average is looking great now. Thanks!

Comment: @phant0m: would you please clarify the reason not to use this class?
Maybe just because a lil problem that I have fixed as I read the comments about that class and tried to fix it.

Comment: I can be generous and share my efforts :) here is my brand new 100% working class: http://mohamedkadri.com/code.html.
Now it has much more feature like pagination and generation of meta links and much more. I will be always updating it.

Comment: now who voted down my question I want some vote ups :)

Comment: @medk: I countered the votedown with an upvote as soon as I saw it (quite a while ago), so I can't be of service in this area. In the end, this turned out to be a good question. :)

Comment: @medk: No proper error handling (@ - not that this is all), they always check whether tables exist before they run a query, they don't wrap mysql_query either (why would they, if there's no error handling?), DELETE $table? That's invalid, I think, so says mysql.com. It provides no ways to escape stuff properly, you cannot tell the class what connection details to use, it keeps the result in $this->result, it doesn't clean it before the query is run, it sanitizes column names?? saves you from: typing 2 words when doing SELECT, inconsistent behaviour (your question) need I go on? (comment limit)

Comment: @phant0m: Sorry but I didn't get the point :) did you compare my version (http://mohamedkadri.com/code.html) against the original (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: @phant0m: it's not the best solution ever but I think it might help

Comment: Yes, until I saw HTML inside a Database-functionality-related class. I can see that some points about the select stuff have been fixed though, but you've introduced new less-than-optimal stuff ;)

Comment: are you talking about the pagination table? it's just because I found that it's the best way to display a well structured pagination nav, as I really developed this for my own specific usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code can be reduced to:

```
$query = @mysql_query( $q );

if ( $query ) {
    $this->num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $query );
    if($this->num_rows) {
        $this->result = array();
        while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))) {
            $this->result[] = $row;
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->result = null;
    }
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

**Reference:** [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Tip: Read and browse the documentation.

Comment: Why use a foreach instead of a while? Also your bracket's don't balance.

Comment: @jpiasetz: Wanted to use while... had two things in my head... thanks!

Comment: ok can you tell me where should this be put?

Comment: @medk: That is the whole code (see my latest update).

Answer (score 1):

using your code (I think) this is what you need:

```
if ( mysql_num_rows( $query ) > 1 ) {
    $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
} else if ( mysql_num_rows( $query ) < 1 ) {
    $this->result = null;
} else {
    // adding index 0 to $this->result[0] or you could use $i (maybe)
    $this->result[0][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]]; 
}
```